# Best multivariate approximation scheme for scattered data approximation

Tags: approximation, data-analysis

what is the best multivariate approximation scheme for scattered data approximation on a set E of points in $R^d$?

Comment: In which sense do you want to approximate these data?  Do you want to minimize an error measure, like least squares?  Or do you want the approximation to be as compact as possible?

Comment: I want it to be as smooth as possible and minimize the error.